# Using current location to show directions to a destination using an in app MapView ios 6

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, ios6-maps

I am trying to find how to provide directions to a certain location using the in app MapView.  I want my app to pull the users current location(which I have accomplished), then I want the MapView to use that information to provide turn by turn directions to a certain destination.  Is this even possible with iOS SDK 6.0 and xcode 4.5?

Comment: are you yet to start on this? or you have done some development and are stuck at some point?

Answer (score 0):

U can Use `Google` `Directional` Map `api` .simply Implement

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([_iLat doubleValue],[_iLong    doubleValue]);


 MKPlacemark* placeMark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coordinate  addressDictionary:nil];
 MKMapItem *destination =  [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placeMark];

 if([destination respondsToSelector:@selector(openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:)])
{
    //using iOS6 native maps app
    [destination openInMapsWithLaunchOptions:@{MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeKey:MKLaunchOptionsDirectionsModeDriving}];

}
```